# Is it possible to run java application in both commandline / as a webservice

Tags: java, jax-ws, bitcoin, webservice-client, json-rpc

I wantto create a java application like a bitcoin client.But it will work on command-line cmd and as a webservice to to other client consulting my client.Which tecnology should I use to handle my task.Please show me an example explanining issue

Comment: You could also just add a class to package that has a runnable Main - that calls your webservice, I often do that when testing web services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Expections

Guess this is what you are expecting

1. Run a Java program from command line or as OS service
2. That program should be a webservice exposing some APIs to other consumers

## Solution

- You can do that with the help of Spring MVC, Spring Boot and Maven

## Reasons

- Spring MVC could be used for exposing your businesses as REST webservice
- Spring Boot could be used to start a webservice application as a normal Java Application(using main class), without use of external web servers like Tomcat or Jetty
- Maven build tool could be used for creating a fat jar(single jar file with all dependencies) from the Spring Boot application
- You will be running the generated fat jar from command line still the services will be exposed as REST services

## Reference

- Use https://start.spring.io/
- This Spring's own hosted tool will generate all the boiler plate codes for you. You just have to import the downloaded zip into your workspace and add your business logic
- For building a fat jar you don't have to do anything special. Just run `mvn clean install`. The boiler plate will have a pom.xml file that will take care of generating fat jar

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed, elegant answer.
Your last sentence has caught my attention.
I'm going to give the program to my stockbroker customers, they can access the information in my system with this program.
In doing so, it will use commandline or browser.
Is there an error in this fiction.
Still, I can solve it with what you're talking about.

Comment: I never used the spring boot and maven.Is there an example that covers the technologies that you mention to complete this task.

Comment: Edited the answer, hope that will help you to kick start very fast(perhaps that is the motive of spring boot).

Comment: In this way, Can I make requests from both the command line and the browser?

Comment: When you mean request, I guess you mean HTTP request. Yes, you can from browser as well as cmd. For cmd you have to use cURL commands.

Comment: this is what I want to do; Send http request from both console and postman.
But using cUrl, I want to make a request without writing url starting with http, just like the bitcoin client.
I can request with cUrl as attached from the console but I don't want it.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbsGA.png

Comment: Then you should be running a cron job within that jar itself to call the service.